# What does the balance mean in EtherScan?

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan

For example, [IDEX](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2a0c0DBEcC7E4D658f48E01e3fA353F44050c208#tokentxns) has 40,767.582633880607462483 Ether. But I use [BalanceAt](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/ethclient/ethclient.go) function and only get 15.884 Ether. Why? Should I traversal all the tokens and query `balanceOf("0x2a0c0DBEcC7E4D658f48E01e3fA353F44050c208")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are caught up to the latest block on your Geth node?

Try running:

```
eth.syncing
```

Using Web3.js, I get the correct result for the amount of ether, using Infura/Metamask as my Ethereum provider:

https://shawntabrizi.com/ethbalance/

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
            window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
            window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/noapikey"));
        }
    })
    function getBalance() {
        var address, wei, balance
        address = document.getElementById("address").value
        try {
            web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, wei) {
                if (!error) {
                    var balance = web3.fromWei(wei, 'ether');
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = balance + " ETH";
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = err;
        }
    }
```

At the time of writing this post:

> 40857.081452818949926701 ETH

Comment: I didn't run a geth node, I use infura and go-ethereum/ethclient. So it should be no sync problem. I don't know why…

Comment: my fault……the balance overflow uint64